Simple Proof of Existence/Uniqueness of Differential Equations Defining $sin$ and $cos$.
Some define $f(t) = (cos(t), sin(t))$ as the solution to the differential equation:
$$f''(t) = -f(t)$$
$$f(0) = (1, 0)$$
$$f'(0) = (0, 1)$$
... or equivalently as the solution to a linear system of first order equations:
$$f(t) = (x(t), y(t))$$
$$f'(t) = (-y(t), x(t))$$
$$f(0) = (1, 0)$$
My question is how such definitions get to assume the existence/uniqueness of a solution. Solving with a characteristic polynomial with imaginary roots would assume some pre-existing definition of $e^{ix}$. Using the known Taylor series could demonstrate existence, but then we'd still need non-elementary results to demonstrate uniqueness, and it feels like then we may as well use the series as the definition (as is done in many cases).
Is there any elementary way to prove that these basic differential equations have a unique solution? By elementary, I mean using the definitions and basic properties of derivatives and integrals (eg Fundamental Theorem of Calculus).

see this and this

@SineoftheTime I am not sure that they are quite as elementary.
